# Passing escape characters into javascript templates with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

This is what I have inside my Flask app.py.

```
data = "date,New York,San Francisco,Austin\n20111001,63.4,62.7,72.2\n20111002,58,59.9,67.7\n" \
        "20111003,53.3,59.1,69.4\n20111004,55.7,58.8,68\n20111005,64.2,58.7,72.4\n20111006,58.8,57,77\n" \
        "20111007,57.9,56.7,82.3\n20111008,61.8,56.8,78.9\n20111009,69.3,56.7,68.8\n20111010,71.2,60.1,68.7\n" 
return render_template("chart.html", title="NY, SF, Austin Comparision", data=data)
```

And this is what I have inside the html page's  tags. The problem is that Javascript is treating the "\n" as an actual new line. Is there a way to encode it so that it doesn't without having to double backslash everything in app.py

```
var data = "{{ data}}";
```

Comment: use {{{data}}} this will do that

Comment: trying that gave me an error 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use replace filter

```
var data = "{{ data|replace("\n","\\n") }}";
```